# How can I migrate Team Foundation Server 2013 Work Items to a new TFS Git Repository?

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, git-tf

I'm busy migrating a Team Foundation Server 2012 Repository to a Git repository running in TFS 2013.

I'm using the recommended process:

1. Clone a Git repository form TFS using git-tf.
2. Create the Git repository using Visual Studio 2013 connected to a TFS 2013 server.
3. Copy the cloned repository into the newly created local git repository (excluding the conf file).
4. Commit and Sync the changes back into the TFS 2013 Git repository.

This process keeps the code change history intact, but it does not import the Work Items for the project.

Is there a better way to migrate from TFS 2012 to TFS GIT 2013 that will keep the TFS Work items intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a tool that migrates Work Items:

1. Excel - you can export and import using excell but you loose history and state
2. TFS Integration Tools - you can migrate history but it is complex
3. API - this is by far the best way although you need coding knowledge.

If you contact me directly I can give you access to some code that may be useful.

Comment: Hi, is there anyway you can post the code here or link to a public repo?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, there is a better way...

1. Don't use git-tf to migrate (except if don't have branches). Use git-tfs instead (that support branches and export metadatas)!
2. The last time I tried, `TFS Integration Tools` didn't support TFS2013 (and nothing seems to have changed) and crashed.

Otherwise, I could not explain better than what I have already done in [git-tfs documentation](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md#migrate-toward-tfs2013-git-repository-keeping-workitems)

Comment: Thanks for the post Phillipe.